# How to get First Symbol value present in the table

Tags: jquery

I have got a table

```
<table id="1dtopg" class="gaintable table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="thheaders">Symbol</th>
         <th class="thheaders">Close</th>
         <th class="thheaders">Rs Chg</th>
         <th class="thheaders">% Chg</th>
         <th class="thheaders">As On</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>KAYA</td>
         <td>1215.15</td>
         <td class="greenclass">139.80</td>
         <td class="greenclass">11.50</td>
         <td class="">2015-12-18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>NIFTYEES</td>
         <td>7925.00</td>
         <td class="greenclass">85.00</td>
         <td class="greenclass">1.07</td>
         <td class="">2015-12-18</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the First Symbol name (that is KAYA in this case )

I have tried as

```
var symbol_nmae = $('#1dtopg').find(' tbody tr:first').val();

alert(symbol_nmae);
```

But its returning empty ,could you please let me know how to get the value

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/24/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
var symbol_nmae = $('#1dtopg').find('tbody tr td:first').html();
```

- td has no `val()`, but `html()` (or `text()`) instead
- you were accessing first `<tr>`, while need `<tr>` and first `<td>` in it

Demo:

```js
var symbol_nmae = $('#1dtopg').find('tbody tr td:first').html();

alert(symbol_nmae)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="1dtopg" class="gaintable table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="thheaders">Symbol</th>
         <th class="thheaders">Close</th>
         <th class="thheaders">Rs Chg</th>
         <th class="thheaders">% Chg</th>
         <th class="thheaders">As On</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>KAYA</td>
         <td>1215.15</td>
         <td class="greenclass">139.80</td>
         <td class="greenclass">11.50</td>
         <td class="">2015-12-18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>NIFTYEES</td>
         <td>7925.00</td>
         <td class="greenclass">85.00</td>
         <td class="greenclass">1.07</td>
         <td class="">2015-12-18</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```